# saving files created by avisynth

Tags: video, video-capture

I have written a short script using avisynth. It takes a number of videos, stacks them, and adds some text.

I can open the script file in virtualDub and save it as an avi file from there, but what I would like is a way to do this without human action in the process. e.g. have a command line that opens the script in virtualdub, sets the video encoding (maybe this step can be done using the avisynth script?) and saves the output as an avi file.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I think I got this one:

I found a command line tool called avs2avi (www.avs2avi.org). pretty much all I needed :)

Hope this would benefit someone else as well.

Thanks,
Yair

Comment: This only works with ancient VFW filters (it's just a wrapper around virtualdub) have you found anything newer - that can use x264 or ffmpeg?

Answer (score 3):

Answering my one comment, x264 can read avs and write it's regular output

```
x264 example.avs -o example.mp4 --rest_of_x264_options
```

Answer (score 1):

[Avidemux](http://www.avidemux.org/) + `avsproxy` can process `avs` scripts..  video **and** audio streams.
Note, that although quite useful, `x264` can only process the video stream.

`avsproxy` comes packaged with [Avidemux](http://www.avidemux.org/).. both come in GUI and command line versions... 
Here is a good basic [GUI tutorial by example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H8l7yw-XtNY)

This works for Windows and Linux. In Linux, it requires that `wine` is installed).